# Trying to pop elements from the array but only 6 of them getting popped before the loop interrupts

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

I have two functions:

1. Select all elements with id and adds ID's of the element to the array which is 12 elements.
2. Unselects those elements and removes from the array. However, when I run 2 function it interrupts after 6 iterations and I will still have 6 more.

   ```
   var modal = document.getElementById("Child");
   var domElements = modal.querySelectorAll('[id]')
   var elementInDom;
   for(var i=0; i<domElements.length; i++){
     elementInDom = domElements[i].id;
     if(this.selectedZones.includes(elementInDom)){

        this.selectedZones.pop(elementInDom)
     }
   ```

Comment: Are you iterating over and removing from the same array?

Comment: Yes, selectedZones has 12 elements and I removing from it

Comment: Maybe you have copies of this element inside your ```this.selectedZones``` and you are removing only first element of this array which which fit this condition ?

Comment: This isn't enough code. Where and how is selectedZones defined?